# $f$ is convex and $f(10)$, $f(20)$ given. Find the smallest value of $f(7)$.

Tags: convex-analysis

> If a convex function exists $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and satisfies $f(10) = -4$ and $f(20) = 30$, how should I find the smallest value for $f(7)$?

I have tried finding the linear equations between the two points $f(10)$, $f(20)$ and just input $f(7)$ to get a value since all linear functions are convex/concave. But I am unsure the value I calculated (which is $-71/5$) is the smallest value possible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $10=a(7)+(1-a)(20)$ where $a=\frac {10} {13}$. Hence $-4=f(10) \leq af(7)+(1-a)(30)$. This gives lower bound for $f(7)$ and this value is attained when $f$ is a linear function. [ If you draw the straight line passing through the points $(10,-4), (20,30)$ then you get  the graph of a convex function whose value at $7$ is $-\frac {71} 5$ the lower bound you get from above inequality].

Comment: What formula should I be referring to understand the comment above? I have solved my question just simply finding the linear function between f(10) and f(20) and substituting f(7) to find the answer

Comment: @jixubi I have just use then definition of convexity. Whenever $x<y<z$ we can write $y$ in the form $ax+(1-a)z$ and the use the definition of convexity: $f(y)\leq af(x)+(1-a)f(z)$.

Answer (score 0):

You must have
$$f(10) =f\left(\frac{10}{13} \times 7 + \frac{3}{13} \times 20\right) \leq \frac{10}{13} \times f(7) + \frac{3}{13} \times f(20)$$

So $$-4 \leq \frac{10}{13} \times f(7) + \frac{3}{13} \times 30$$

i.e.
$$f(7) \geq -\frac{71}{5} $$

Now you can check that it is the lower bound. Indeed, the function
$$f : x \mapsto \frac{17}{5}x - 38$$

is convex, satisfies $f(10)=-4$ and $f(20)=30$, and $f(7)=-\frac{71}{5}$.

Comment: What formula should I be referring to understand the comment above? I have solved my question just simply finding the linear function between f(10) and f(20) and substituting f(7) to find the answer

Comment: First part of my answer shows that for any function with the hypothesis, you must have $f(7) \geq -71/5$. Then I give an explicit example where this bound is attained (same as yours), which proves that the smallest value is exactly $-71/5$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply im still trying to understand how you derive this equation.

Comment: Which equation ?

Comment: The first line of your answer :)

Comment: This is the definition of convexity :) $f(tx+(1-t)y)\leq tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, and all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$.